# PHP Unknown error: getEntityNamespace is deprecated since Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using symfony 2.4.2  :
in execute this commande :

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities SdzBlogBundle:Article

i have this error in my console :

```
 PHP Unknown error:  getEntityNamespace is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. Use getA
liasNamespace instead in C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Do
ctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry.php on line 129
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\app\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\app\c
onsole:27
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www
\Symfony1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:1
24
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\ven
dor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:9
6
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() C:\wamp\www\Symfo
ny1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:193
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\v
endor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:896
PHP   7. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand-
>execute() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Con
sole\Command\Command.php:252
PHP   8. Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry->getEntityNamespace() C:\wamp\w
ww\Symfony1\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Comma
nd\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php:101
PHP   9. trigger_error() C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Do
ctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry.php:129
Generating entity "Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article"
  > backing up Article.php to Article.php~
  > generating Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article
```

Comment: Your folder path is C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\ your not trying to use part of Symfony1 with Symfony2 are you? Have you tried 'composer update' ensuring all your dependencies are using up to date version's of everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed since v1.3.0-beta1 of Doctrine Bundle : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/commit/80a7198c470d74755db64aa3f75898f3808778b7

Try

```
composer update doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```